# Why doesn't Location.add(0, 1, 0) set a new location one block above?

Tags: java, location, minecraft, bukkit

<strike>I want to, if the player breaks a block, break the block above, too, but this code will just drop the original block (`brokenBlock`) and not even break the block above...</strike>

What did I do wrong?

```
@EventHandler
public void onDestroy(BlockBreakEvent event)
{
    Player player = event.getPlayer();

    if (player.getItemInHand().getType() == Material.WOOD_PICKAXE)
    {
        Location brokenBlock = event.getBlock().getLocation();

        Location up = brokenBlock.add(0, 1, 0);
        up.getBlock().breakNaturally();
    }
}
```

After some experimenting, I found the problem, but not the answer.

I made the code above shorter, so it's nicer to read, but the original contains two breakNaturally() methods.When I try to execute both or more, it acts strangely and doesn't work anymore.

**Here's the real code:**

```
@EventHandler
public void onDestroy(BlockBreakEvent event)
{
    Player player = event.getPlayer();

    if (player.getItemInHand().getType() == Material.WOOD_PICKAXE)
    {
        Location brokenBlock = event.getBlock().getLocation();

        Location up = brokenBlock.add(0, 1, 0);
        Location down = brokenBlock.add(0, -1, 0);

        up.getBlock().breakNaturally();
        down.getBlock().breakNaturally();
    }
}
```

Comment: We don't all remember the entire Minecraft API. I suggest reading a javadoc, and asking us about any part of the javadoc that you do not understand, or do not expect.

Comment: Your code looks right, are you sure you have added registered the event? Consider adding a log in the function.

Comment: @Afsa Yes I did. Ok, I'm trying it right now.

Comment: @Unihedron Sorry it isn't over :P do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>Note: Relevant links to resources to CraftBukkit code are now unavailable due to Bukkit being taken down by DMCA requests, they will be linked to Bukkit-Bleeding and be subject to link rot.</sup>

Contrary to your belief, [`Location`](https://github.com/Wolvereness/Bukkit-Bleeding/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit/Location.java) objects are *not* `@Immutable` (as in immutability of object, not the annotation). Firstly, here you have the source code for [`Location.add(double, double, double)`](https://github.com/Wolvereness/Bukkit-Bleeding/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit/Location.java#L326-L340):

```
/**
 * Adds the location by another. Not world-aware.
 *
 * @see Vector
 * @param x X coordinate
 * @param y Y coordinate
 * @param z Z coordinate
 * @return the same location
 */
public Location add(double x, double y, double z) {
    this.x += x;
    this.y += y;
    this.z += z;
    return this;
}
```

As you can see, the fields change and returns itself in the process. This is because the location manipulations reuse itself for efficiency, instead of having to call `new` constructs and cache objects.

You're better off using them every time you change them:

```
/* (BlockBreakEvent event) */ {
    Location brokenBlock = event.getBlock().getLocation();

    for (int i = 1; i < 16; i++)
        brokenBlock.add(0, i, 0).getBlock().breakNaturally();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, that answer really was that kind of answer I was looking for :) Also some useful information.